# Empty bibliography and undefined references

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber

My minimal working example. But it does not work.

[Bibliography](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxqacy3axw5l8uj/Facharbeit.bib)

```
%\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-2012-05-30]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

%\usepackage{xunicode}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{hyphsubst}
%\HyphSubstIfExists{ngerman-x-2012-05-30}{%
    %\HyphSubstLet{ngerman}{ngerman-x-2012-05-30}}{}

\usepackage[]{babel}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[autostyle=true, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{libertineotf}
%\usepackage{fnpct}
%\usepackage{ccicons}
%\usepackage{embrac}

%\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}
%\linenumbers

\addbibresource{Facharbeit.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{mierau}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what not works? "Does not work" is not very helpful ... Have you run `bibtex` or `biber`? Which way? What is the content of your `bib` file?

Comment: I've edited this to indent your code: you can do this by putting four spaces before code, or selecting it an using the code button {}. Apart from some more explanation as Kurt suggests, you might like to include the relevant .bib entry, preferable via filecontents. As things stand it will be hard to help.

Comment: It looks like it might be a biber cache problem: something I've experienced a few times. Have a look at http://humtex.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/biber-first-aid-for-data-source-not-found/ and try clearing the cache.

Comment: I'm not on a windows machine, but I think you need to delete everything from the long number and below it. Section 4.1 of the Biber documentation says "To clean up, you can just remove the whole par-<hex_encoded_username> directory/folder and then run the current binary again."

Comment: @EricDanielski: Please read the help for comments: You can (and should) include the person you are answering to.

Comment: @PaulStanley I delete the files and the problem is solved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib)

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Just to have a starting point run the following MWE (store it in a separate directory to avoid changing your file `Facharbeit.bib`). On my system it runs without problems. Please see that I deleted `libertineotf` because I run it with `pdflatex` and then `libertineotf` throws errors.

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78820/empty-bibliography-and-undefined-references

%\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-2012-05-30]{hyphsubst}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%writing file Facharbeit.bib
\begin{filecontents*}{Facharbeit.bib}
@PREAMBLE{ "\providecommand*{\BibTeX}{Bib\TeX} " }

@book{mierau,
    address    = {München},
    title      = {Nationalsozialistische Expeditionspolitik: deutsche Asien-Expeditionen 1933 -- 1945},
    isbn       = {3-8316-0409-6},
    shorttitle = {Nationalsozialistische Expeditionspolitik},
    publisher  = {Utz},
    author     = {Mierau, Peter},
    year       = {2006},
    file       = {DNB, Katalog der Deutschen Nationalbibliothek:C:\Users\ericdanielski\Desktop\FirefoxPortable\Data\profile\zotero\storage\PCUH3IQM\opac.htm;jsessionid=61596D477EE425917EC0601AF3FE83BB.html:text/html}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\listfiles %used packages in log
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Facharbeit.bib}

\title{Wissenschaftliche Auswirkungen der Tibet-Expeditionen während der NS-Zeit}
\author{Eric Danielski}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Vorwort}

Eric Danielski. \cite{mierau} 

\section{Anhang}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Is the field `file` in your `bib` file necceccary?